# question about a tangent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function $y(x)$ satisfies the following perplexed equation:

$$x^2+x \cdot y^3+y^5=16$$

the graph $y(x)$ comes through 3 points with $x=4$. I need to compute the tangent of each of them.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about implicit differentiation ?

Comment: yes I should...

Comment: why are there 3 points where $x=4$? the only real solution is $y=0$

Comment: That is what the excericse says....

Comment: Have a look at this plot:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dkojnupyii

Comment: I need an analytical solution

Comment: Are you sure it's not when $x=-4$? Because the graph does indeed have three intersections there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2+xy^3+y^5=16$$

I'm rather convinced that this question intends to find the tangents where $x=-4$.

$$16-4y^3+y^5=16$$
$$y^3 (y^2 -4)=0$$
$$y=0,\pm2$$

The tangents can be found using the point slope formula and the derivative of the curve.

$$y-y_1 = \frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$$

The derivative is found implicitly.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+x y^3+y^5)=\frac{d}{dx}16$$
$$2x+y^3+3xy^2\frac{dy}{dy}+5y^4\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+y^3}{3xy^2+5y^4}$$

The equations of the tangent lines can now be found. Calculate the derivatives at $(4,0), (4,2),$ and $(4,-2)$ and substitute into the point slope formula above.